# More efficient way to do parent().parent().parent() etc. in jquery

Tags: jquery

In this script I'm writing, I find myself using .parent() up to seven times in a row to get elements.  While this works, it seems like there could/should be an easier way to do this/ function I'm unaware of.  Any ideas other than more specific classes/ids on more elements?

Basically, my question boils down to accessing the div with id `outer` when I have a reference to the span with id 'innerSpan' in the html below:

```
<div id='outer'>
    <a href="some_url">
        <span id="inner">bla bla</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

So currently, I would do something like this:

`var outer = $('#inner').parent().parent()`

and that gets crazy with deeply nested elements.

**Another example:**

Here my html:

```
<div id="options_right">
            <table id="product_options_list" class="table table-bordered">

            <tbody id="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="option_1_val[0]" class="option_table_select">
                            <option value="Red">Red</option>
                            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
                            <option value="Green">Green</option>
                            </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <table class="table sub_options" id="0">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <select name="option_1_sub[0][]" class="option_table_select  sub_option_select">
                                        <option value="">None</option>
                                        <option value="2">Size</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <div class="sub_option_value_holder">
                                        <select name="option_1_sub_val[0][]" class="sub_option_values" style="display:none;"></select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#" class="remove_sub_option btn btn-primary">Remove</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="#" class="add_sub_option btn btn-primary">Add Another</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
```

and my script. i wrote a function and need to pass it the ids of the main rows tbody as well as the secondary tables id so i can dynamically add more rows.  You don't really need that function for this question but basically i get those ids like so:

```
get_suboption_row($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id'), $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id'));
```

thanks

jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4rf/

click the add another to trigger event

Comment: hmmm not sure about Jquery but in vanilla can do it like 
  el.parentNode.parentNode

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have 2 nested tables,
to get what you want you can use this two DOM traversal methods  `.closest()` or `.parents()`

> - [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) Self or ancestor. Self or travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector
> - [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents) Travels up the DOM tree to the document's root element, adding each ancestor element to a temporary collection; it then filters that collection based on a selector if one is supplied

Using nested tables:

```
$(this).closest('table').closest('tbody').attr('id');
```

```
$(this).parents('table').parents('tbody').attr('id');
```

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4rf/28/)**

Comment: I tried doing a .closest('tbody').closest('tbody').attr('id') from within the embedded table but it was returning undefined.  Can you not use it twice?

Comment: @JohnB you don't need to use it twice. just once with the right selector.

Comment: I am late ( I didnt refresh the page), should I delete my answer if its exact duplicate ?

Comment: could you give me an example of how I could get the id on the outer tbody(should be 1) using either of the <a> tags within the embedded table?

Comment: added jsfiddle to the top.  first alert gives me what i want.  second is what i want to do the same thing.  hmmm.  didn't know the ids thing for html 5.  how do I know which version of html I'm running?  !DOCTYPE?

Answer (score 7):

I think [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

If you know the `CSS Class name` for that element, you can call the `closest()` method

```
var thatParent=  $("#someId").closest(".somCSSClassName")
```

So your code cal be rewritten as

```
get_suboption_row($(this).closest("someClass").attr('id'),
                $(this).closest("someOtherClass").attr('id'));
```

EDIT : After seeing your JSfiddle

Use the class name to get the Parent Table.

```
 alert($(this).closest('tbody').closest('.table-bordered').attr('id'));
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4rf/2/

Comment: it would be `$(this).closest("#someId")`. However, if it's an id, it would be better to just use `$("#someId")` since id's must be unique.

Comment: @KevinB : Just a generic example to use closest. so that he can use for any jquery selection

Comment: I tried doing a .closest('tbody').closest('tbody').attr('id') from within the embedded table but it was returning undefined.  Can you not use it twice?

Comment: @JohnB :depends on your Markup. Can you post it on  a jsFiddle ?

Comment: i actually need the id of the tbody as I'm using multiple tbodys with differing Ids.   Or else I could use your code and just add a find('tbody') at the end

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use **eq()** after the **parents()** function

```
get_suboption_row($(this).parents().eq(7);
```