# add active class to main menu using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, menuitem

I have searched a lot for adding active class to the parent menu using `javascript`.

I found many more examples but not a single one is working for me, below is my code

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu1" class="hmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubItem1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubItem2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem2</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubItem1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubItem2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubItem1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubItem1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SubSubItem2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br style="clear: left" />
</div>
```

My requirement is when i click on *SubItem1* then both *Item1* and *SubItem1* should be active.

And when i click on *SubSubItem1* then *SubSubItem1* ,*SubItem1* and *Item1* should be active.

Means when click on any link then its all parent link and the same link should be active.

I have tried with this `javascript` code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.hmenu ul li ul').find('li').click(function () {
            //removing the previous selected menu state
            $('.hmenu').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
            //adding the state for this parent menu
            $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

Actually i don't have any experience with `javascript` coding and unable to figure out the problem in my `code`.

Can anyone suggest me for the same.

Comment: With your current selector (`.hmenu ul li ul').find('li')` you aren't getting al your `li`s.

Comment: actually i don't know that what i am getting with this selector, but when i click on an item there is no change in menu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue comes from `.find('li').click()`.

As you use nestsed `<li>`, this will cause the event to be fired two times when you click on a child `<li>`. This causes problems. Can not you add the `click()` to `<a>` elements?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hmenu a').click(function () {
        //removing the previous selected menu state
        $('.hmenu').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
        //adding the state for this parent menu
        $(this).parents("li").addClass('active');

    });
});
```

It works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/6put8tdx/

---

Note that your page will be bumped to the top while clicking to `a` tab because of `#` anchor. If you want to prevent this, you may pass the event to the function `.click(function (event) {...}` and add `event.preventDefault` inside.

Comment: thank u so much it works fine in the fiddle ,but in my page it is not working.

Comment: my page is in .aspx and i am putting the js code in my master page header

Comment: @TufanChand Maybe should you open a new question because I really can not help you to this point, sorry.

Comment: `$('a').click` ? [slowmotion]NOOOO[/slowmotion]

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Is this considered as bad practice?

Comment: @Delgan sure, it's a bad practice. If you read again your code you can conclude this: *You click an `<a>` element in some article that does some fancy stuff... suddenly there's no active class in `.hmenu`! "Sh^t what happened?"* :) You get the point. Assigning events to every possible `"a"` is a bad idea. (Though the code is cool) So I'd suggest just a different selector like `".hmenu a"`

Comment: Also your code will make the page jump-to-top on every anchor click... not something desirable (at all). PS remember that OP has no absolute clue about JS / jQuery.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Oh, you mean that I should use `$('.hmenu a')`. You are right, this was just an example without considering the page context.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The jumping page is because of anchor tag, right? I could add `preventDefault` but this is up to the OP, and this was not the topic of the question.

Comment: @Delgan (yes `e.preventDefault`) yes, it was no topic but you could spare OP another 15min from searching a solution to that *other* issue ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Hope it suits you (even though it's useless now). :)

Answer (score 3):

If you need the click target to be the LI element (as opposed to Delgan's answer)

you can use `.not()` over the targeted LI's `parents` to prevent messing with the bubbling event targets:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.hmenu').find('li').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();                   // Prevent page jumps due to anchors
    var $par = $(event.target).parents("li"); // get list of parents
    $(".hmenu .active").not( $par ).removeClass("active");  // not them
    $(this).addClass('active');               // let the event propagation do the work
  });

});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.hmenu').find('li').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var $par = $(event.target).parents("li");
    $(".hmenu .active").not($par).removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

});
```

```css
.active > a{
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="menu1" class="hmenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SubItem1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubSubItem1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubSubItem2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">SubItem2</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">SubItem3</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubSubItem1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubSubItem2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item3</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SubItem1</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubSubItem1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubSubItem2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <br style="clear: left" />
    </div>
```

**To better understand the above**
The following example works out-of-the-box, and the clicked one and all it's LI parents get the `"active"` class.
**Why?** Cause the event target is `li`, means any `li` of `.hmenu` - so that click is *attached* to any of them, and clicking the *subsub* LI the event will propagate to the `LI` parents - triggering the same `click` behavior (*this add class*)!

```
$(".hmenu").on("click", "li", function(){
   $(this).addClass("active"); // Wow! Event propagation rulez!!
});
```

But we need to remove existing `.active` and here it gets messy...

```
$(".hmenu").on("click", "li", function(){
   $(".active").removeClass("active"); // triggered on every event bubble :(
   $(this).addClass("active"); // leaving only the main parent with active class
});
```

That's caused by the concurrency that happens while the event bubbles and triggers the same actions for the parent elements.

One way to prevent that concurrency would be using a `setTimeout` of `1`ms:

```
$(".hmenu").on("click", "li", function(){
   $(".active").removeClass("active");
   setTimeout(function(){  // Let the previous finish the bubbling mess
      $(this).addClass("active"); // Yey! all fine! Every LI has the active class
   }, 1);
});
```

But here the timeout of `1ms` can lead to visual "blinking" issues.

Comment: very good explanation thank you. As @Delgan's solution works for me so i m marking his answer as correct answer

Comment: @TufanChand sure! He's got a good answer. I just wanted to shad some light on the real *issues* for a better understanding! :) thx for the reply and happy coding

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
 $(function () {
     $("li a")
       .on("click", function () {
         $(this).toggleClass("active");
         $(this).closest("ul").parent().children("li a").toggleClass("active")
       .parent().parent().parent().children("li a").toggleClass("active");

     });
 });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bzy2wde/)

Traverse from the clicked element. And use `toggleClass()` to avoid the mundane checking if `hasclass` `removeClass` ...

Comment: Be honest you did not tested your example. Also, there's a better way to do `.parent().parent().parent()....` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568722/more-efficient-way-to-do-parent-parent-parent-etc-in-jquery