# Bootstrap 4 nav-pills active using include page

Tags: html, jsp, bootstrap-4, sidenav, nav-pills

I'm working on a internal website for the company I work for and my manager wants me to have the Menu as a jsp include page instead of it being coded into the page like this(which works).

```
<head>
<title>SomeCompany Intranet</title>
<jsp:include page="/jsp/head.jsp"/>
</head>
<body style="min-height: 75rem; padding-top:110px;">
<jsp:include page="/jsp/header.jsp"/>

<div class="sidenav">
   <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">      
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled">Marketing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/marketing/AA.jsp">Agent Access</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/marketing/ItemsCatalog.jsp">Promotional Items Catalog</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/marketing/OrderForm.jsp">Catalog Order Form</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/marketing/TravelForm.jsp">Travel Form</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/marketing/TuitionAssi.jsp">Tuition Assistance Form</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="mainHeader">
<h1>PROMOTIONAL ITEMS CATALOG</h1>
</div>

<div class="tab-content main1">
<iframe src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pdf/PromotionalCatalog 01-20.pdf" width="100%" 
height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

He wants it to look more like this.

```
<head>

<title>SomeCompany Intranet</title>
<jsp:include page="/jsp/head.jsp"/>

</head>

<body style="min-height: 75rem; padding-top:110px;">
<jsp:include page="/jsp/header.jsp"/>

<div class="sidenav">
  <jsp:include page="/jsp/marketing/TestMenu.jsp"
</div>

<div class="mainHeader">
  <h1>PROMOTIONAL ITEMS CATALOG</h1>
</div>

<div class="tab-content main1">
 <iframe src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pdf/PromotionalCatalog 01-20.pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
```

This is the TestMenu.jsp

```
<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" aria-orientation="vertical">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">      
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled">Marketing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/marketing/AA.jsp">Agent Access</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/marketing/ItemsCatalog.jsp">Promotional Items Catalog</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/marketing/OrderForm.jsp">Catalog Order Form</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/marketing/TravelForm.jsp">Travel Form</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/marketing/TuitionAssi.jsp">Tuition Assistance Form</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

My nav pills go active but they don't take me to the actual pages. But if I remove the active from the TestMenu the links work. It's such a small thing that I'm trying to accomplish which is highlighting the proper pills and I just need help figuring it out. Or at least point me in the right direction.

[image: Wrong Pill-tab selected]

Even though I'm in the 2020 Corporate Calendar page it shows Project Team Guidelines highlighted.

Comment: adding a working demo code might help to understand where problem exists.

Comment: @Swati I'm not sure how to add multiple pages using Stack Snippets. I would need to include the sidenav menu pages along with the TestMenu.jsp in order to see it in action.

Comment: I think problem here is with path ,as your navbar is inside some folder you need change your path accordingly. Hover on `a` tag and see what path it's showing .

Comment: But the paths work the only think that doesn't seem to work is changing the active pill to the proper pill-tab. I'll post a picture.

Comment: do you have written any script to apply active class to your tab?

Comment: No I don't have a script added.

Comment: @Swati do you know what script I should have to apply active class to the tab?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087198/add-active-class-to-main-menu-using-javascript) . Current how do you apply active class to tab ?

Comment: @Swati now would this be going in between <script> </script> in the jsp or in a Javascript file? I'm sorry I've never used Javascript before.

Comment: that should be going inside `<script></script>` tags