# Hide elements by array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to hide certain `tr`'s of a table based on certain labels inside a `td`

```
$('label:contains("Severity")').parent().parent().toggle();
$('label:contains("Priority")').parent().parent().toggle();
$('label:contains("Select Profile")').parent().parent().toggle();
$('label:contains("Assign To")').parent().parent().toggle();
$('label:contains("Steps To Reproduce")').parent().parent().toggle();
$('label:contains("Additional Information")').parent().parent().toggle();
$('label:contains("Attach Tags")').parent().parent().toggle();
$('label:contains("Reproducibility")').parent().parent().toggle();
```

This works, I know it could be a lot neater though. How would I add these strings to an array and do the `parent().parent().toggle();` foreach of the entries in the array?

For Bonus points, is there a neater way of doing `parent().parent()`?

Comment: For parent().parent(), you can use the closest thing if that serves your purpose and if the parent's parent can be identified in a similar way.
like: **$('xyz').closest('.pqr')**

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var array = [
    "Severity",
    "Priority",
    "Select Profile",
    "Assign To",
    "Steps To Reproduce",
    "Additional Information",
    "Attach Tags",
    "Reproducibility",
];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $('label:contains("' + array[i] + '")').parent().parent().toggle();
}
```

For a better way to do `.parent().parent()` see this SO post: [More efficient way to do parent().parent().parent() etc. in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568722/more-efficient-way-to-do-parent-parent-parent-etc-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Because of jQuery's set-based nature, you can use a [selector group](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping). The advantage to that is that you do **one** DOM query rather than a series of them. This is particularly important with `:contains`, because `:contains` is a jQuery extension, not something supported by the browser's built-in selector engine.

You could do it literally:

```
$('label:contains("Severity"), label:contains("Priority"), label:contains("Select Profile"), label:contains("Assign To")', label:contains("Steps To Reproduce"), label:contains("Additional Information"), label:contains("Attach Tags"), label:contains("Reproducibility")').parent().parent().toggle();
```

That's really ugly, though, so:

```
var selector = ["Severity", "Priority", "Select Profile", "Assign To", "Steps To Reproduce", "Additional Information", "Attach Tags", "Reproducibility"]
    .map(function(name) {
        return 'label:contains(" + text + ")';
    })
    .join(",");
$(selector).parent().parent().toggle();
```

or if you really want to:

```
$(["Severity", "Priority", "Select Profile", "Assign To", "Steps To Reproduce", "Additional Information", "Attach Tags", "Reproducibility"]
    .map(function(text) {
        return 'label:contains("' + text + '")';
    })
    .join(",")
).parent().parent().toggle();
```

with an ES2015+ arrow function and template literal:

```
$(["Severity", "Priority", "Select Profile", "Assign To", "Steps To Reproduce", "Additional Information", "Attach Tags", "Reproducibility"]
    .map(text => `label:contains("${text}")`)
    .join(",")
).parent().parent().toggle();
```

---

> I have this code to hide certain tr of a table based on certain labels inside a td

You can also replace `.parent().parent()` with `.closest('tr')` as [DJ Yadav suggested in  a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066713/hide-elements-by-array#comment75157623_44066713), to make things a bit more flexible (e.g., if you put your `label` in a `span` later for some reason, you don't break your code).

Answer (score 1):

```js
[
    "Severity",
    "Priority",
    "Select Profile",
    "Assign To",
    "Steps To Reproduce",
    "Additional Information",
    "Attach Tags",
    "Reproducibility",
].forEach(function(el) {
    $('label:contains("' + el + '")').parent().parent().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, it's better to use a class or `data` attribute to select upon rather  than using `:contains` selectors like you are. What if you want to change your text, now you have to change your logic as well!

It's better to create a class like 'hide-me', so you can select on those like `$(".hide-me")`. Then if you want to find a specific parent element such as a `<tr>` tag, it's better to be explicit about it (and thus not use `parent().parent()` etc). Again, what if you want to wrap your label in another `div` to add some padding? Your logic is broken!

Instead make use of the `$.parents()` or `$.closest()` function which work like `$.find()` except they traverses upwards (both travel through ancestors, only `$.closest()` stops at the first match, whereas `$.parents()` travels to the document root, while adding each match to a list). Then pass a selector for a `<tr>` tag so that you can actually select the rows.

It would look like this (if you'd use the class I suggested)

```
$(".hide-me").closest("tr").toggle();
```

This will work for all rows at once, so there is no need to do it for multiple texts.

If you insist in using the contains or at least on the necessity of specifying it for each row, then indeed use an array like this:

```
$.each(array('text1','text2', 'text3' ..), function(index, value) {
   $('label:contains('+value+')').closest("tr").toggle();
}
```

Also, if you're only using `$.toggle()` to hide once, use `$.hide()` instead of `$.toggle()`. While both work, `$.toggle()` suggests that you're actually switching between `display:block` and `display:none`.

Comment: closest() goes up, find() goes down

Answer (score -3):

Simply use.

```
$(array [1]).hide();
```