# Jquery change name value with array style

Tags: jquery

First, when clicking the add-school button at the bottom.
and in: `school[0][variable]` I want to increase the number of 0 by 1, I want to only interfere with 0 without destroying other values

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $k = 0;
  $k < 10;
  
  $("#addschool").click(function() {
    $k++;
    $(".school-copy:last").clone().appendTo(".close-add");

    $(".school-copy:last input").attr("name",
      $(".school-copy:last input").attr("name").replace("0", $k))
    $(".school-copy:last input").attr("name");

    $k++;
  });
  
});
```

```html
<div class="row school-copy mt-3" name="school-copy">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <input class="text-input defaultText form-control shadow-none school-variables" type="text" placeholder="Okul Adı" name="school[0][name]" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <input class="text-input defaultText form-control shadow-none school-variables" type="text" placeholder="Şehir" name="school[0][city]" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <input class="text-input defaultText form-control shadow-none school-variables" type="text" placeholder="Bölüm" name="school[0][faculty]" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <input class="text-input defaultText datepicker form-control shadow-none school-variables" type="date" placeholder="Mezuniyet Tarihi" name="school[0][graduation_date]" value="" id="dp1661514196187">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-4 delete-btn-append d-flex">
    <div class="mobile-show col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-4">
      <a id="addschool" class="btn btn-primary add-school"><span class="bt_bb_button_text"><i style="padding-bottom: 6px" class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-4">
      <a class="btn btn-danger m-l-10" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().parent().remove()"><span class="bt_bb_button_text"><i
                                        class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain in your own words this line: `$k = 0; $k<10;` ?

Comment: Please, before diving any further into JS, read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#declarations

Comment: Read also: [more-efficient-way-to-do-parent-parent-parent-etc-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568722/more-efficient-way-to-do-parent-parent-parent-etc-in-jquery)

Comment: Stop using inline `on*` JS handlers in HTML. JS should be in one place only, and that's its respective tag or file.

Comment: Please do take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].  You will also benefit from reading [mcve].

Comment: Can you explain *exactly* how and when you are checking whether the name attribute has changed?  Are you using the browser *inspect element*?   Or `console.log($(".school-copy:last input").attr("name"));`

Comment: As you've not detailed the issue we can only guess - is that that all 3 inputs are being changed?  city/faculty -> name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more complete script

Note I use delegation as you should, and I cache the element that was cloned

Also note, if you want to renumber the fields when one school in the middle is deleted, we can do that quite simply

```js
$(function() {
  $(".close-add").on("click", ".add-school", function() {
    const $copy = $(".school-copy").first().clone(); // take the FIRST so it has [0] in the names
    $copy.appendTo(".close-add");
    const k = $(".close-add .school-copy").length; // this is a better counter
    $("input", $copy).each(function() {
      const name = $(this).attr("name");
      $(this).attr("name", name.replace("0", k - 1)); // length is one more than we want
    });
  })
  $(".close-add").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).closest(".school-copy").remove();
    const k = $(".close-add .school-copy").length; // if you need this
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" />

<div class="close-add">
  <div class="row school-copy mt-3">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input class="text-input defaultText form-control shadow-none school-variables" type="text" placeholder="Okul Adı" name="school[0][name]" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input class="text-input defaultText form-control shadow-none school-variables" type="text" placeholder="Şehir" name="school[0][city]" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <input class="text-input defaultText form-control shadow-none school-variables" type="text" placeholder="Bölüm" name="school[0][faculty]" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <input class="text-input defaultText datepicker form-control shadow-none school-variables" type="date" placeholder="Mezuniyet Tarihi" name="school[0][graduation_date]" value="" id="dp1661514196187">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-4 delete-btn-append d-flex">
      <div class="mobile-show col-xs-3"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-4">
        <a class="btn btn-primary shadow-none add-school"><span class="bt_bb_button_text"><i style="padding-bottom: 6px" class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-4">
        <a class="btn btn-danger m-l-10 remove"><span class="bt_bb_button_text"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```